# Sort the list of objects by the field in included object

Tags: java, list, class, sorting, comparator

I want to sort the list of objects potentialHS by the distance in ElementWithDistance class but I can't get the distnace field in this way. After calling getElementWithDistance i can't call getDistance. How can I sort my list by the the field in included class?

```
List<PotentialHS> potentialHS = potentialHS.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(PotentialHS :: getElementWithDistance)).collect(Collectors.toList());

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
public class PotentialHS {
    private Integer density;
    private Double startDistance;
    private Double lastDistance;
    private List<PMValue> pmv;
    private ElementWithDistance elementWithDistance;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
public class ElementWithDistance  {
    private Long elementId;
    private Double distance;
    private Type type;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PotentialHS :: getElementWithDistance
```

is shorthand for:

```
(PotentialHS x) -> x.getElementWithDistance()
```

In other words, it says: To sort this stream, applying the following operation:

- Per item in the stream, fetch the thing you get by invoking `getElementWithDistance()` on it. Treat that as a double, then sort by those doubles.

Which obviously won't work - `ElementWithDistance` is not a double.

You want:

```
(PotentialHS x) -> x.getElementWithDistance().getDistance();
```

Note also how that is a `Double`, not a `double`, so that's a mistake (fix it. `Double` is the non-primitive wrapper type around `double`, and you really don't want it. It has an extra value (`null`), and is grievously inefficient. It also means you can't do things like 'give me the largest double in this stream'.

This gets you:

```
List<PotentialHS> potentialHS = potentialHS.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(x -> x.getElementWithDistance().getDistance())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```